# Why won't bullet vs enemy collision function work?

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

trying to use game.physics.arcade.overlap() for collision between the goblin and bullets.

thanks in advance.

```
function update() {
    game.physics.arcade.overlap(bullets, goblinSprite, bulletHitEnemy, null, this);

    //Shoot on LeftMouse click
    game.input.onDown.add(fire, this);             
}

function bulletHitEnemy (goblinSprite, bullet) {
    console.log('collision');
    bullet.kill();
    goblinSprite.kill();

}

function fire() {
    if (game.time.now > nextFire && bullets.countDead() > 0)
    {
        nextFire = game.time.now + fireRate;

        var bullet = bullets.getFirstDead();

        bullet.reset(sprite.x + 5, sprite.y + 5);

        game.physics.arcade.moveToPointer(bullet, 500);
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you know it's not working? Do you not see 'collision' in the log?

Comment: Nothing on the console log and neither the goblin or bullet are destroying themselves on collision.

Comment: does it get to the update function when ran? how does this involve java?

Comment: Yes, everything else works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue before. I fixed it by calling the collision function using 'this'.
For example instead of:

```
 game.physics.arcade.overlap(bullets, goblinSprite, bulletHitEnemy, null, this);
```

Try:

```
 game.physics.arcade.overlap(bullets, goblinSprite, this.bulletHitEnemy, null, this);
```

Hope that helps.